# Excel formula to calculate percentage growth needed to achieve specific return as the data set grows

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

Looking for help on the following scenario:
as we move through the year and data is provided each month, I need a calculation that shows how many months it would take to reach a cumulative 90% if we are currently at 85% ITD. Prior months are a variety of 80-90% achievements, but assuming each out month achieved 100%, how long would it take for the rolling cumulative average to also hit 90%?

Answer (score 1):

It's more a mathematical question than Excel:

```
t1 = Current available months
t2 = Future months
ITD1 = Current ITD (which is 85%)
ITD2 = Future ITD (which is 100%)
ITD = Target ITD (which is 90%)

ITD = ( ITD1 * t1 + ITD2 * t2 ) / ( t1 + t2 )

0.90 t1 + 0.90 t2 = 0.85 t1 + 1.00 t2

0.05 t1           = 0.10 t2
     t1           = 2    t2
```

So basically, you'll half times of the current months to achieve your target ITD; if it's been **12 months**, you'll need **6 months**; if it's been **30**, then it's **15**.